# Converting DNG inline in a ConTeXt document?

Tags: graphics, context, conversion

I'm writing some code that automatically exports TeX for context to convert into a report. The content that this code manipulates includes images in .dng format. While I'm aware that I can add an extra step `convert foo.dng foo.pdf` as a shell command, this will almost double (to 20 gigs) the size of the tarballs we're throwing around.

Is there a way to use a module or other means to losslessly convert (I briefly looked at dng -> jbig, but that didn't seem to work) images for final inclusion into the document?

Comment: luatex/pdftex can only include jpeg (including jbig), png, pdf, and a restricted version of eps files. So, you'll have to convert dng to one of these. The conversion to jpeg/png will be lossy; when you convert to pdf, you loose the compression features of dng. So, you'll have to choose your pick.

Comment: Well, right now I'm converting to PDF, but the main question is how to invoke that conversion via lua, since it's not done automagically.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the DNG files inplace when doing `\externalfigure`.  You only have to register a converter on the Lua level.  Of course you need to have the required external programs ready.

```
\startluacode
figures.converters.dng.pdf = function(oldname,newname,resolution)
    logs.report("graphics","using imagemagick to convert " .. oldname)
    os.execute("convert " .. oldname .. " " .. newname)
end
\stopluacode

\starttext

\externalfigure[foo.dng]

\stoptext
```

When run this will generate a file `m_k_i_v_foo.dng.pdf`.